Telerik Reports paging
We are getting an unexpected scrollbar which allows us to scroll between pages one and two of our reports list. We would rather just use the nav bar to switch between both pages.
Is there something perhaps in the backend designer that needs to be updated ? Some property somewhere ? Or just a css class override on the front end ?
ex/
class="trv-page-wrapper active"

And using the navbar, we would rather just switch between pages via those left/right arrow icons - and NOT have the scrollbar shown here in the screenshow.

Now if I can only figure out how to hide that scroll bar.
thanks,
Bob
